# Bootstrap 4 change spacing between columns wraps underneath instead of side to side

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

What I try to achieve is to have a 2 divs that take over 6 columns bith with some space between them of 1px.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6 bg-dark text-light text-center mr-1"> Hello </div>
<div class="col-6  bg-danger text-light text-center"> Hello </div>
</div>
</div>
```

But for some reason when Ι try to achieveit, the other item goes underneath (wraps) instead being side to side. Do you know how I can make having 6-column with some space between items and still remain side to side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gutter (spacing between columns) is created with padding, not margins. When you adjust the margins it throws off the grid. You can use inner DIV's...

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-6 text-light text-center">
            <div class="bg-dark mr-1">Hello</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-light text-center">
            <div class="bg-danger">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or, force the `row` no to wrap with `flex-nowrap`...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
        <div class="col-6 bg-dark text-light text-center mr-1"> Hello </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger text-light text-center"> Hello </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or, simply use the [padding utils](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) to adjust the column spacing.

https://codeply.com/go/p4NpmmRxmb

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- Control the column width, and how they should appear on different devices -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:yellow;">50%</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:orange;">50%</div>
</div>
</div>
```